# How do I view all localStorage entries from a subdomain

Tags: javascript, opera, local-storage

I want to see all localStorage entries on all subdomain pages of a site, not one particular page, how can I do this? I need to do this in Opera.

Comment: `localStorage` is persistent across pages, you can iterate like `for(var key in localStorage)` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to inspect what is stored (for example for debugging), both opera:webstorage and Opera's developer tools (Opera Dragonfly) should be able to help you.